# Possibility of changing the signature for Embedded Users - DocuSign API

Tags: docusignapi

We are trying to integrate with DocuSign using the DocuSign REST API. What we have observed is that when a user who is not registered with DocuSign and is coming into DocuSign from the partner system as an embedded user, he does not see the prompts to adopt or draw a signature and Sign (Adopt and Sign feature). Where as these prompts are always seen for external users i.e. when emails are triggered from DocuSign directly to the signers mail box and this user happens to be an unregistered user, he will always see these prompts to adopt a suggestion signature or draw a new signature.

The external users also see the prompts to 'register with DocuSign' once they have completed signing the Documents.

One more thing observed while making our portal users embedded users is that DocuSign does not shoot emails to their mailboxes when all parties have completed signing. but this email is sent to all the external users.

Are all these behavior expected when it comes to integrating using the API or is it there a way to achieve these prompts and notifications via the API too.

I would be more than grateful if anyone could help us with this information.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer is that everything described above is expected under certain conditions/configurations. Users who do NOT have DocuSign user accounts will be prompted to adopt their signature each time (since there is no account to 'save' it). For embedded signing, as long as you pass the same name/email@/clientUserID for a specific individual, DocuSign will remember the signature they adopted and re-apply it for future signature events.

- If for some reason you want to clear the saved signature (https://www.docusign.com/p/RESTAPIGuide/RESTAPIGuide.htm#REST%20API%20References/Delete%20Captive%20Recipient%20Signature.htm?Highlight=delete%20captive)

The external users also see the prompts to 'register with DocuSign' once they have completed signing the Documents.

- This is configurable in your account as "Signer can create account" under Preferences -> Features.

One more thing observed while making our portal users embedded users is that DocuSign does not shoot emails to their mailboxes when all parties have completed signing. but this email is sent to all the external users.

- This is configurable in your account as "Use Envelope Complete Email for (non-suppressed) Embedded Signers" under Preferences -> Features.

Comment: Hi Luis, External users see the prompt to register with DocuSign once they are done signing but the embedded users don't see this prompt. Do you know any way this can be achieved ?

Comment: Set "Signer can create account=false" on your DS account settings under Preferences -> Features. IF that particular signer already has a DocuSign account, then they absolutely will be prompted to 'login to their account'. If they do NOT have an account, they will simply see the download/print dialog box.

Comment: Hi Luis, Thanks a lot for you help. but i'm still a little confused. When i did the above setting, definitely stopped seeing the sign up form and saw only the download/print dialog box when external users complete signing. but i need some more help on this part - IF that particular signer already has a DocuSign account, then they absolutely will be prompted to 'login to their account'. This is not happening for me. I'm sending via the REST API. My request message has the email address which is registered as a demo account with its own signature. Still system does not enforce this user to login

Comment: Hi Luis, apologies for the confusion. I think i misunderstood some of the things. I now understand that the prompt to login to one's account comes for the registered docusign users AFTER they have completed signing. Again, one observation is that this is coming up only in case of external users and not embedded users. Embedded users are automatically brought back to the partner system based on the return url provided as part of the request message. Please let me know if my understanding is incorrect.